# Return the second most recent value in a specific windows time frame for each individual row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Imagine the following table :

```
UserName    paymentType      date(YYYY-MM-DD)          Status   
x           transaction      2016-09-16                1         
x           UpdateStatus     2016-10-22                2        
x           transaction      2017-01-08                2        
x           transaction      2017-06-12                2         
x           UpdateStatus     2017-08-27                3
x           transaction      2018-11-08                3
x           transaction      2018-11-08                3
```

I would like to be able to query the list of all `UpdateStatus` `paymentType` event with the previous status associated for each status update event. Something like this :

```
UserName  paymentType    date(YYYY-MM-DD)     Status    Previous_status          
x         UpdateStatus   2016-10-22           2         1       
x         UpdateStatus   2017-08-27           3         2
```

I know that I need to use a sub query to query the whole table first them filtering only `where paymentType='UpdateStatus'` for the global query. However I don't how I can get the previous status associated with each status update. I think I need to use a windows time frame function somewhere. Basically the `previous_status` need to be the last status where date is inferior to the UpdateStatus date event for each row.

Here is the query I was able to build so far...

```
SELECT
  UserName,
  paymentType,
  date,
  status,
  Sub.Previous_status
FROM
  `Payment_table` as p
JOIN (
  SELECT 
  UserName,
  < get the Previous_status here > as previous_status 
  FROM
  `Payment_table` as s
  ) AS Sub ON 
  p.UserName=sub.UserName
WHERE
  paymentType = 'UpdateStatus'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select pt.*
from (select pt.*, lag(status) over (order by date) as prev_status
      from payment_table pt
     ) pt
where paymentType = 'UpdateStatus';
```

You need to do the `lag()` in the subquery, so it is not affected by the filter.